# No photos (count == 0) in most recent checkin that returned after requesting complete user object

Tags: foursquare

When I request the complete user it has most recent checkin object with photos.count == 0 but that is not true. Is it known bug?

Comment: Can you e-mail api@foursquare.com with the full API request you're making with the incorrect count (and tell us the specific checkin id with the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Writing in this as my question is related.

This is my foursquare user id 62901880

Question related to foursquare checkin workflow:
I tried checkin multiple times to a location with Shout and Photo. I don't see picture showing up every time. Is this internal workflow to not associate photo with checkin conditionally.
a. https://foursquare.com/banjoinc/checkin/5213c82c11d218279cec4623 does not show photo on UI
b. https://foursquare.com/banjoinc/checkin/5213b59f11d2943dcf21e138 shows picture.

Question related to /v2/checkins/recent api endpoint:
a. I get a photo count of zero with some checkins containing photo
https://foursquare.com/facher/checkin/5212cae9498e2a1f77f9fa3a checkin while fetching response from above endpoint did not had any photos earlier using cron job. Is it possible ?

Question related to /v2 endpoints in general:
There are 2 types of objects Compact and Complete documented with all endpoints. Is there an option that could be passed to fetch Compact or Complete objects.

Please let me know if you need more info